# Trouble deploying PowerBuilder Web Service to IIS from within PowerBuilder

Tags: web-services, iis-7, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I've developed a web service in PowerBuilder 12. I can use the project painter to push it out to IIS 7 running on my local machine (localhost) and it works fine. I can also deploy it to an msi, copy the msi to the server and install it and it works. What I can't do is deploy directly to IIS 7 running on the web server from the painter in PowerBuilder. When I try I get:

```
Checking IIS server...
Deployed failed.
```

and the Errors tab says:

```
IIS is not accessible. Please check the server address and port number.
```

I've made sure that the IIS 6 compatibility is installed. Any ideas?

**Update**
As per DisplacedGuy, I installed Web Deploy 3.0 on the server. I also made sure that port 8172 was open. But I still get the same error message.

I've been able to determine via Process Monitor some of the steps that PowerBuilder is taking when I press the deploy button. Simplified version: It's creating a vbs file that it copies to the server. It then runs this script on the server. The script outputs a text file with information about IIS. It then copies this text file back to my computer. It's at this point that I get the "IIS is not accessible" method.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. I had to install **Web Deploy** on the remote IIS server and make sure **port 8172** is opened up as well.  Once you do that, the publish from PB works beautifully.

Hope this helps.

*edit 10-31-12* I tried changing my IIS server address in the Deploy tab of the project painter to an IIS website that I know doesn't exist, like matrix/dummyfolder to see if I would get the same message you got.  I did not, the message was "Cannot find server "matrix/fummyfolder" on network. I  didn't think this was the problem but figured I'd at least try for you.

*edit 11-2-12* Here are some common web deploy problems/requirements:

1. IIS Manager permission for the site/app you are trying to connect
   with.  Set via IIS manager, click on site and set deploy properties.
2. A delegation rule for msdeploy, that states that you are
   allowed to do ContentPath operations (see [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler)).
3. Actual filesystem/ACL access to the files.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. My server had Web Deploy 2.0 installed. I installed Web Deploy 3.0 on it. I also verified that port 8172 is open. However, I still get the same error about IIS is not accessible.

Comment: I added some extra debugging info. Three common issues with web deploy are related to permissions.  Are you deploying as Administrator (if you are allowed to), it is the easiest way? Also check the IIS logs you might find hints there. Maybe look at the firewall logs to be safe.  If running on a cloud server you typically need to add ports as part of network setup. Good luck.